# checking for exceptions in counting islands

Tags: javascript, algorithm, matrix, data-structures

when it comes to matrix traversals and any kind of search, I find that I often need to validate a potential item to either add to my queue or recurse over.

say we're looking at this matrix:

```
var matrixTest = [
      [1,1,0,0,0], 
      [1,1,0,0,0], 
      [0,0,1,0,0], 
      [0,0,0,1,1]
]
```

In this case, I am iterating over all items and performing a BFS (marking as visited) when I encounter a 1.

I have a subroutine within my BFS function that, given a coordinate r and c, it validates all possible paths leading from it (r+1, r-1, c+1, c-1).

The problem is with this piece of code

```
if(!visitMap[r+1][c] && matrix[r+1][c] === 1) {
      q.push([r+1, c])
    }
```

visitMap is a matrix I created alongside the algorithm to ensure I'm not processing a point twice

matrix is the input matrix

However, it appears that I need to validate inputs before testing because JavaScript throws this error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property '3' of undefined
```

I presume this means that my "r+1" expression lies outside the bounds of the matrix, and thus processes as undefined.

It seems exceedingly tedious to add another layer of if/then flow to check the bounds of r+1, r-1, c+1, AND c-1.

Is there a particular code pattern you'd recommend using to avoid having to do this many times?

otherwise I think the code block will look like this:

```
if (r+1 < matrix.length) {

    if(!visitMap[r+1][c] && matrix[r+1][c] === 1) {
         q.push([r+1, c])
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to encapsulate  the validation of bounds and your condition inside a function like this:

```
function pushToQueue(visitMap, matrix, r, c) { 
    if( typeof(matrix[r]) == "undefined"
        || typeof(matrix[r][c]) == "undefined" )  {
    return false; 
    }
    return !visitMap[r][c] && matrix[r][c] === 1; 
}
```

And you can call  it like this:

```
if(pushToQueue(visitMap, matrix, r + 1, c)) {
   q.push([r+1, c]); 
}

if(pushToQueue(visitMap, matrix, r - 1, c)) {
  q.push([r-1, c]); 
} 
// etc ...
```

Comment: `if( !matrix[r] || !matrix[c] )` would only work for a square matrix. The OP test matrix is 5x4 and this function will always return `false` and never actually execute the 2nd test for (r = 3, c = 4).

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to use a function each time you try to access the matrix at a position which is susceptible to be outside the bounds.

So, `matrix[r+1][c] === 1` would become `readMatrix(c, r+1) === 1`.

This should have a very low impact on the overall performance, even in imbricated loops. (If any branch predictor is involved in the final machine code, it should make the right guess most of the time, because you are inside the matrix most of the time.)

```js
var matrix = [
  [1,1,0,0,0], 
  [1,1,0,0,0], 
  [0,0,1,0,0], 
  [0,0,0,1,1]
];

function readMatrix(x, y) {
  return matrix[y] && matrix[y][x] !== undefined ? matrix[y][x] : 0;
}

console.log(readMatrix(0, 0));
console.log(readMatrix(0, 7));
console.log(readMatrix(7, 0));
```